# How to return value from Dispatcher.Invoke,Which uses delegate function as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, delegates, dispatcher

**Delegate Declaration**

```
 delegate bool newDelegate(ref byte[] b,COMMAND req);
```

**Dispatcher Call**

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke( new newDelegate(MainWindow.processBuffer), b, request);
```

I am trying to invoke a function **processBuffer** that processes the sent buffer and updates the UI and on completion it should return success or failure status as `bool` value.
I am using the following syntax to invoke the function. 
**Syntax:** 
**public object Invoke (Delegate method, params object[] args)**

How do i access the returned value ?Am i missing anything?Or doing it wrong?

Comment: Note that `CurrentDispatcher` will create a new Dispatcher for the current thread of it does not already have one. That is certainly not what you want.

Comment: Use the invoke which returns a value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Threading_Dispatcher_Invoke__1_System_Func___0__System_Windows_Threading_DispatcherPriority_

Comment: You mean i need to create a Dispatcher object then i should invoke the method using the instance?

Comment: You may want to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Comment: Besides that, you don't need to declare the callback as delegate. Just call `var result = Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => yourCallback(ref b, request));`

Comment: Using the `var result = Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => yourCallback(ref b, request));` is giving a error: Cannot convert lambda expression to System.Delegate.

Comment: It's this overload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Threading_Dispatcher_Invoke__1_System_Func___0__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
var returnedValue = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
  .Invoke(new newDelegate(MainWindow.processBuffer), b, request);
```

Another syntax:

```
var returnedValue = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
  .Invoke((newDelegate)(MainWindow.processBuffer), b, request);
```

The `bool` will be boxed in an `object`.